# Access Gantry/Rockettheme template params from a Joomla 2.5 Component

Tags: php, joomla2.5

G'Day,
I have a custom component I have designed for Joomla 2.5. Currently I am using a Rockettheme template.
The problem I am having is that my design in the component is not responsive so it looks terrible on iphone/android etc.

Is there a way for me to access the rockettheme/gantry framework parameters (from my component) to see which layout the user is viewing. At the bottom of most sites the user has the ability to change which layout they view if using a mobile device via a desktop/mobile button at the bottom of the screen. I would like to access this setting.... and in my view.html.php file adjust which layout I will display.

Is this possible? I haven't the slightest clue where to start with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested I managed to create a solution which includes the Gantry Framework and accesses the gantry cookies to determine which layout the user is viewing. (either the normal default.php file or default_phone.php)

Here we go:
In your view.html.php file:

```
    //-----------------
    // Add the Gantry framework and access the iphone switcher values!
    //-----------------
    $gantry_path = JPATH_SITE . '/libraries/gantry/gantry.php';
    if (file_exists($gantry_path))
    {
        require_once($gantry_path);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error " . JText::_('Unable to find Gantry library.  Please make sure you have it installed.');
        die;
    }

    global $gantry;

    $prefix = 'viewswitcher-'.$gantry->get('template_prefix');
    $cookiename = $prefix.$gantry->browser->platform.'-switcher';
    $cookie = JRequest::getVar($cookiename, false, 'COOKIE', 'STRING'); 

    if($cookie == true)
    {
        //User is viewing from iphone mode
        $tpl = 'phone'; // this will call the layout file named: default_phone.php (It MUST be called default_xxx.php)
    }
    else{
        //User is viewing from desktop - Do nothing! - view.html.php will call the normal default.php layout
    }
    //------------------------
    // End Gantry Framework
    //------------------------
```

So i'm not sure if it's the correct or advisable way to do it but it works a charm.